# Renaming a Visual Studio .NET 2008 C++ project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I didn't think too hard when initially naming my Visual Studio C++ project and now want to rename it.  I'd love to avoid doing a replace all on the name of the project (and renaming all files in the project directory), because this would be error prone and tedious.  Is there a way to rename the project within Visual Studio?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score -1):

In Solution Explorer - right click your project, click on 'Rename'

EDIT - for refactoring there is [limited support for Rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxxabwd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in VS2008.  Otherwise you need something like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Rename).

Comment: I tried this, but it only renames the project; the new name doesn't propagate to the rest of the filenames, classnames, etc.

Comment: You want to refactor the project not rename it, then. See EDIT

Comment: What about other instances of the name that are not in the code, such as under "properties > startup project"?